# Api Symfony com Auth0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, symfony, auth

Alguém me pode ajudar é que eu estou com problemas a implementar o Auth0 para autenticar uma api eu estou a ver este exemplo https://github.com/auth0/jwt-auth-bundle/tree/master/example só que o problema e que não sei como é que consigo gerar o token .

Obrigado